# Ruby on Rails and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a polymorphic Attachment model to save images uploaded by users. Users can set any of their own as a profile pic.

To this, I created an "avatar_id" column in the User database to basically save the attachment id to create the reference. I also added an avatar action to the User model:

```
def avatar 
  self.attachments.first(:conditions => ['id = ?', self.avatar_id])
end
```

The problem is that if I try to make this work

```
<%= @user.avatar.url %>
```

It doesn't work because the url method doesn't exist. I need to specify that is an paperclip object but I don't get where and how I should do it. I'm probably missing something  obviously here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Attachment` model should have a set of attachment fields: maybe `attachment_file_name`, `attachment_content_size`, etc.

So when you reference `@user.avatar`, you're really just referencing the entire `Attachment` record rather than the paperclip-specific columns.

Try this, substituting "attachment" for whatever you called your paperclip columns:

```
<%= @user.avatar.attachment.url %>
```